# How would I rewrite without __proto__

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using **Node.JS** and **ExpressJS**. The following code is used to extend the Errors object with my own messages and works well enough, but I understand that `__proto__` is non-standard.

**How would I rewrite the following code without the `__proto__`?**

```
var AccessDenied = exports.AccessDenied = function(message) {
    this.name = 'AccessDenied';
    this.message = message;
    Error.call(this, message);
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, arguments.callee);
};
AccessDenied.prototype.__proto__ = Error.prototype;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.create()` to make the new prototype object, and add a non enumerable `construtor` property back in.

```
AccessDenied.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: AccessDenied,
        writeable: true,
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false
    }
});
```

---

Or if you don't care about the `constructor` property:

```
AccessDenied.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"use strict";

/**
 * Module dependencies.
*/
var sys = require("sys");

var CustomException = function() {
    Error.call(this, arguments);    
};
sys.inherits(CustomException, Error);

exports = module.exports = CustomException;
```

Comment: I'm curious why you set `exports = module.exports = CustomException`? What does this do? I thought you either used `exports` or `module.exports` in a file, not both.

Comment: @ShaneStillwell `exports` just points to `module.exports`. By default it's an empty object, so you can assign new keys to either and it just works (e.g. `exports.thing = 42`). However, if you do `exports = 42`, you overwrite the `exports` variable, which is local to the module, but `module.exports` will still point to the empty object.

Using both may seem superfluous, but it also works the other way around: if you overwrite `module.exports`, `exports` will still point to that empty object. So to prevent problems elsewhere in the module, you overwrite by assigning to both.

Answer (score 1):

```
var AccessDenied = exports.AccessDenied = function ( message ) { /*...*/ };
var F = function ( ) { };
F.prototype = Error.prototype;
AccessDenied.prototype = new F();
```